# How can I access EC2 instance using Access Key ID?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to access (SSH) Linux EC2 instance, I have following information available.
Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
Is there any way to login EC2 with above information?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need the private key that matches the public key that was deployed to the instance when it was created.

Answer (score 0):

With the Access, and Secret key you can use the api based tools (cli. powershell, boto) to perform some actions at the instance level but you won't be able to ssh into it without the key generated (or selected) at the instance's launch time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to login through windows machine ( using Putty ) you need private key ie .ppk file & if you are going to login through linux then you need .pem key.

eg : ssh username@hostname -i ~/Keys/key.pem  .......ssh From Linux Box

Access Key ID and Secret Access Key are used for AWS-IAM (AWS Identity and Access Management) to authenticate AWS-IAM users eg: to work on s3cmd command line

For Details of creating IAM-Users in AWS refer

http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/

Thank you !